# MoviePy failing to execute because it cannot find ffmpeg on my macOS

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I have a macbook pro running sonoma latest version, i have installed ffmpeg with brew and its located at `/opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg`

Im trying to run this script but i get the error :

```
from moviepy.editor import *
from moviepy.video.tools.subtitles import SubtitlesClip
from moviepy.config import change_settings
import os

os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = 1
os.environ["IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE"] = r"/opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg"

generator = lambda txt: TextClip(txt, font='Arial', fontsize=24, color='white')
subs = [((0, 4), 'subs1'),
        ((4, 9), 'subs2'),
        ((9, 12), 'subs3'),
        ((12, 16), 'subs4')]

subtitles = SubtitlesClip(subs, generator)

video = VideoFileClip("video.mp4")
result = CompositeVideoClip([video, subtitles.set_pos(('center', 'bottom'))])

result.write_videofile("output.mp4", fps=video.fps, temp_audiofile="temp-audio.m4a", remove_temp=True, codec="libx264",
                       audio_codec="aac")
```

error :
`RuntimeError: No ffmpeg exe could be found. Install ffmpeg on your system, or set the IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE environment variable.`

I tried reinstalling ffmpeg and installing it in the env of the project but still no luck.

Comment: I am also currently having this issue, have not found a solution yet